# Проблема с парсингом JSON'a

Tags: android, json

Имеется строка с JSON'ом:

```
{"response":{"count":544495,"items":[358358919,358357662,358352453,358351002,358350593,358345630,358338466,358337444,358332410,358322758]}}
```

Я пытаюсь получить `count` в `int'овую` переменную, а `items` в `JSONArray` (чтобы потом перевести в `ArrayList<String>`):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

int count = jsonObject.getInt("count");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
```

Но, в результате, получаю ошибки:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for count
>
> org.json.JSONException: No value for items

Почему выскакивает ошибка, если, по смыслу, данные поля есть? И какие поля тогда нужно запрашивать, чтобы получить нужный мне результат?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, `Error:(67, 84) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String json = "{\"response\":{\"count\":544495,\"items\":[358358919,358357662,358352453,358351002,358350593,358345630,358338466,358337444,358332410,358322758]}}";

    try {
        JSONObject rootJSON = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(json));
        JSONObject response =  rootJSON.getJSONObject("response");//вы забыли эту строку
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(response.getInt("count")));

        JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
            int item = items.getInt(i);
            Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(item));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: А что делает `new JSONToken`?

Comment: @bukashka101, для лучшей совместимости

Comment: А... Ну тогда, на всякий случай добавлю (хотя у меня без этого заработало :)).